# modifying the Open CV video detection tutorial

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm some how new to open CV and, just doing some experiments with the tutorials in order to figure out some information about the usage and functionalists of this library, in one of the tutorials which is already placed on Open CV official website, there is a piece of code which is about detection of some trained faces and prediction of faces on webcam,[Face Recognition in videos](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html)

Now I'm trying to modify the code in order to use a saved picture from local database and give the same output with a rectangle on the detected face and a label above it, I have modified the code (after line 88 of the code mentioned in tutorial) in this way:

```
CascadeClassifier haar_cascade;
haar_cascade.load(fn_haar);

for(;;) {

    Mat gray;
    Mat original;
    gray = imread("F:\datasets\23.jpg",0);
    original = imread("F:\datasets\23.jpg");
    vector< Rect_<int> > faces;
    haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);
    for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {   
        Rect face_i = faces[i];
        Mat face = gray(face_i);
        Mat face_resized;
        cv::resize(face, face_resized, Size(im_width, im_height), 1.0, 1.0, INTER_CUBIC);

        // predict:
        int prediction = model->predict(face_resized);

        // visualize:
        rectangle(original, face_i, CV_RGB(0, 255,0), 1);
        string box_text = format("Prediction = %d", prediction);
        int pos_x = std::max(face_i.tl().x - 10, 0);
        int pos_y = std::max(face_i.tl().y - 10, 0);
        putText(original, box_text, Point(pos_x, pos_y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2.0);
    }
    // Show the result:
    imshow("face_recognizer", original);
    // And display it:
    char key = (char) waitKey(20);
    // Exit this loop on escape:
    if(key == 27)
        break;
}
```

but when I execute the code it reports "OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in unknown function" can any one help me with this problem to detect and solve the mistake in code please?

Comment: Not really experienced with OpenCV, but if I had this error, I would fire up gdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adjust your image path there, should be `"F:\\datasets\\23.jpg" or "F:/datasets/23.jpg"`

(single backslashes in filenames are somewhat problematic, use 2 or avoid them)

for the future, the error is symptomatic for empty or invalid mats, so doing checks on any ressource you load is kind of a must-have. like:

```
gray = imread("F:/datasets/23.jpg",0);
if ( gray.empty() )
{
    cerr << "could not load it!";
    return -1;
}
```

same for the cascade:

```
if ( ! haar_cascade.load(fn_haar) )
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: can you mention that how should the variable original be initiated in this tutorial? I think this variable cause problem. what should be the initial value for this variable?

Comment: There is a variable called original which has been used to print the rectangle and label above it , it's from type of Mat, but I'm having difficulties initiating it:
`original = imread("F:/datasets/23.jpg");`
I just want to be sure of the way it should be initiated

Comment: ah, ok. maybe put it in one line, `Mat original=imread(...)`  but nothing will save you from checking, if imread() succeeded or not. you need the same `if(original.empty())` code as for the other

Comment: btw, since you're only checking 2 images, you could skip the enclosing for(;;) loop, and change  waitKey(20); to  waitKey(0); so it waits forever for a keypress

Comment: thinking twice about it, maybe it's better to load only the original image(yes, and check if succeeded!), and get the grayscale like `Mat gray; cvtColor(original, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);` from that. will be faster, and saves you from checking twice